# Help Identifying Parts of a Battery Management Board

Tags: batteries, pcb, pcb-design, battery-charging, circuit-design

I am currently way over my head in a personal project to design and create a 5 cell battery protection system. I'm fairly confident that I've correctly cloned the cell balancing section (section C) of the BMS in the picture.

My question is what is the name / purpose of sections A and B in the picture below. I know section A has to do with the maximum current capacity of the BMS, but I don't know what to google to find out more about what specifically it does. This particular board is rated for 60A continuous, but each of the 8 HY4306P MOSFETs is [rated](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/HUAYI-HY4306B_C330368.pdf) for 230A continuous, which is throwing me off for reverse-engineering it's purpose.

I'm sure section B is all pretty specific use-case stuff that would require actual part numbers to understand what it does, but I'm pretty stumped on that as well.
[image: 12S LiPo BMS (figure 1)]

If needed, I can add another picture of the back of the board, but there's basically nothing on it. A bunch of heatsinking under the mosfets, and a few passives under section C.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Where is the schematic?  And why are you sure that section A is not also used to balance the charge on cells.  In some  sophisticated cell balance circuits the charge is transferred between batteries rather then simply depleting the charge on cells which have more charge then others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A= 100A current reg.
B=12S protection cct.
C= balancers.

Applicable for

```
43V    (3.6V * 12S) lithium battery & packs
44V    (3.7V * 12S) lithium battery & packs
50.4V (4.2V * 12S) lithium battery & packs
Lithium battery (Li-ion)
Prismatic Lithium Polymer battery (Li-Po)
 
Technical Parameters:
Balanced current: 60mA (VCELL = 3.90V when)
Balanced for: 4.20 ± 0.05 V
Over-charged Protection: 4.2 ± 0.05 V
Over-charged Release: 4.05 ± 0.05 V
Over-discharged Protection: 2.9 ± 0.05 V
Over-charged delay: 5mS
Over-current Protecton: 100 A
Supports Max. Continuing Discharge Current: 100A
Static power consumption: less than 200uA
Short-circuit protection function: disconnect the load from the recovery.
 
Dimension: 200mm * 110mm * 20mm (L*W*T) - with Radiating Board
 
The main functions: Over-charged, Over-discharged protection, short circuit protection, over-current protection, with Balancing function.
```

Comment: I think wherever you got your technical parameters from is wrong. The Board measures 120x50x10mm. Its only rated for 60A. The listing is [here](https://www.ebay.com/itm/44V-48V-50-4V-12S-60A-Lithium-ion-Li-ion-LiPo-Li-Polymer-Battery-BMS-PCB-System/221644780045). But thanks for the circuit names.

Comment: If you use a good heatsink it can do 100A but sealed in a skateboard only 60